# How can I tell which of my pages got adsense clicks?

Tags: google-adsense

How can I tell which of my pages got adsense clicks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Google analytics and associate your adsense account with the Analytics account.

Comment: I have found this to be somewhat unreliable though. Perhaps its just me but I often find that the stats don't update for a very long time, or sometimes don't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in PHP, obviously it's easily applicable in any other language

```
// I configured te campaign whit the addres ending in &origen=adwords:SRAM
$origen = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'origen');
if($origen!=FALSE) {
        // log, mail, whatever
}
```

Comment: How ist that even an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Associate Google Analytics with your AdSense account. Then, in Analytics under "Content" is an AdSense report link. Click Show Full Report and you'll get a list of your pages that had adsense clicks and how many clicks they got.

Analytics is always more reliable over larger data sets, but you'll still get a pretty solid idea of which pages are generating the clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You could make different ads for different pages and use custom channels in adsense.